# Fix to Eclipse 3.6.2 bug that displays Combo text right aligned

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

Eclipse 3.6.2 has this bug documented here

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=358183

There are a couple of suggested workarounds.  The first one did not work for me, but the second one did.

```
   combo.addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener() {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(final Event e) {
            //We need the original text, not the displayed substring which would return methods such as combo.getText() or combo.getItem(combo.getSelectionIndex())   
            String text = combo.getItem((int) combo.getData("selectionIndex"));
            //reset text limit
            combo.setTextLimit(text.length());
            GC gc = new GC(combo);
            //exact dimensions of selected text            
            int textWidth = gc.stringExtent(text).x;
            int magicConst = 14;
            int comboWidth = combo.getClientArea().width - magicConst;
            //In case the text is wider then the area on which it's displayed, we need to set a textLimit
            if (textWidth > comboWidth) {
                //find text limit - first we set it according to average char width of our text
                int averageCharWidth = textWidth / text.length();
                int tempLimit = comboWidth / averageCharWidth;
                //sometimes on resize it can happen that computed tempLimit is greater than text length
                if (tempLimit >= text.length()) {
                    tempLimit = text.length() - 1;
                }
                //then we fine-tune the limit - it must be as precise as possible    
                while (tempLimit > 0 && (comboWidth < gc.stringExtent(text.substring(0, tempLimit + 1)).x)) {
                    tempLimit--;
                }
                //textLimit must not be zero
                if (tempLimit == 0) {
                    tempLimit++;
                }
                combo.setTextLimit(tempLimit);
            }
            combo.setText(text);
            gc.dispose();
        }
    });
```

However, when I implement this, the widget thinks that user has changed some data (state change).  This may be because of the call above to

```
combo.setText(text);
```

As our system is set up, there is a call to

```
org.eclipse.ui.forms.ManagedForm.isDirty()
```

which results in a prompt to the user to save the data every time user exits the form.

I am not familiar at all with SWT or jFace.  Can anyone tell me

1. Is there any other way to get around the Eclipse 3.6 bug?
2. If not, is there a way for me to clear the dirty state of the Combo box so that the user is not prompted to save?

Thanks

Comment: Something must be adding a modify listener to pick up the change to the text. Where is this happening? You may be able to remove the listener temporarily.

Comment: Thanks.  I did see in the code that did this combo.addModifyListener(modifyListener); I removed it before the setText call and added it afterwards.  It seemed to work. So it is the modify listener that is setting the dirty flag?  Thank a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just setting the text of a `Combo` won't automatically set a `ManagedForm` to be dirty. So you must be adding a modify listener to the combo in order to do the set dirty.

You can remove the modify listener from the combo just before you do the `setText` and then add it back after the `setText`. This should stop the dirty flag from being set.

Comment: You were right about the modify listener. I had done as suggested and it is working.  Thank you.